# SOLR Not Displaying New Fields Added to Schema

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.10.2 for search and have a pretty simple set up.  However when I added new fields I am not seeing them show up.  I have tried manually deleting the data folder as well as reloading the core and none of the new fields are showing up.

Is there a trick to getting SOLR to reload?  I just added simple date and text fields mimicking what already works in my SOLR implementation.

Comment: You do not seem them show up .. where? Do you query over the admin UI? Did you fill the fields? Solr will not show empty fields.

Comment: also, feel free to show us your schema.xml, solrconfig.xml and way how you add new docs